# Convert Text to Integer in JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, tampermonkey

I am trying to use Tampermonkey to find a UTC time offset and return it as as a time. The website shows an offset which I pull here

```
waitForKeyElements (".UTCText", getTZ_Offset);
```

which returns a string

```
console.log ("Found timezone offset: ", tzOffset);
```

usually like this `08:00` It can be `+ or -`

Then i want to convert that into actual time. Eg if UTC time is `00:00`, I would like to print a string "The users time is 08:00" if the offset was +08:00.

I thought i could use momentjs to get UTC time `moment().utcOffset(tzOffset)` and pass the offset.

When i do that it just returns NaN

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe this is related to your [original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56885121/634824).  But also, you have tagged this with [tag:momentjs].  Why?  You haven't asked anything about Moment.  If you did want to use Moment for converting a time using a UTC offset, its [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) function would be useful, but you do not need to convert to minutes to use that.

Comment: Also, your choice of terminology is inaccurate and slightly confuses what you are asking.  There is no such thing as "a UTC timezone".  If you have a value like `UTC-08:00` (or just `-08:00`), that is an "offset from UTC", or "a UTC offset", or a "time zone offset".  Keep in mind that a time zone is much more than just an offset (read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)).

Comment: There is also no such thing as "UTC format" (from your other question), as UTC is not a *format*.  The usual format for offsets `"±HH:MM"` is part of the ISO 8601 format specification, and many others.  There are also *other* formats that include offsets from UTC in different ways.

Comment: Also, one cannot take an offset by itself and "return it as a local time".  A time and an offset are two different concepts.  You can apply an offset to a given UTC time to return a local time, or you can return the *current* time in a given offset, but you can't just convert an offset to a local time.

Comment: @MattJohnson I tried to use  ```moment().utcOffset() ``` and pass the offset that I returned ```tzOffset``` but it says NaN, I have edited my question for clarity

Comment: Are you including the sign?  It is required.  Also you probably want to call `format` on the resulting moment object to get a string.

Comment: It looks like it is partially working now but it adds the offset to my system time +10:00 instead of UTC time. I am using moment.utc().utcOffset()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the part before the `:` by 60, and add it to the second part:

```js
const tzOffset = '08:00';
const [hourOffset, minuteOffset] = tzOffset.split(':').map(Number);

const totalMinuteOffset = hourOffset * 60 + minuteOffset;
console.log(totalMinuteOffset);
```

If the input may be negative, then check that as well:

```js
const tzOffset = '-08:00';
const [_, neg, hourOffset, minuteOffset] = tzOffset.match(/(-)?(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);

const totalMinuteOffset = (neg ? -1 : 1) * (hourOffset * 60 + Number(minuteOffset));
console.log(totalMinuteOffset);
```

A [few time zones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html) differ from UTC not only by hours, but by minutes as well (eg, UTC +5:30, UTC +9:30), so just `parseInt`, even if it worked, wouldn't be reliable everywhere.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the answer and advice.

Comment: This doesn't handle negative offsets correctly.  For example, `'-09:30'` is interpreted as `(-9 * 60) + 30 == -510`, but it should be interpreted as `-((9 * 60) + 30) == -570`.